# Custom validation attribute not working with MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

**EDIT :** There was a issue on github for this problem, **it's solved**. It's working now.

I want to implement a custom validation attribute to check file properties.

I made this :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomFileCheckAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult("error message");

        IFormFile file = value as IFormFile;
        if (file == null)
            return new ValidationResult("error message");

        if (file.Length < MyCustomFileConstants.FileMinLength)
            return new ValidationResult("error message");

        if (file.Length > MyCustomFileConstants.FileMaxLength)
            return new ValidationResult("error message");

        if (file.ContentType != MyCustomFileConstants.FileAuthorizedContentType)
            return new ValidationResult("error message");

        file = null;
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And in my view model I have this :

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [CustomFileCheck]
    public IFormFile FileToHandle { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    { }
}
```

When I pick no file, my attribute is used but if I pick a file, my attribute isn't executed and ModelState is always valid.

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: No. I made a static class helper but it's not the correct way to do that, an attribute would have been cleaner. If anyone has a solution please post it :)

Comment: Replace true to false in https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/FormFileModelBinder.cs#L70 and remove https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Validation/ValidationVisitor.cs#L218 Have not tested for side effects!

Comment: @chba what do you mean by replacing ? is it not microsoft code ? how can we change it ?

Comment: @elhampour ASP.NET Core is open source. Btw, I have seen a while ago changes in repo (dev branch) that fixed this issue.

Comment: @chba Yes the issue is fixed. It's working now